# Copernicus Sentinel - National Mirrors and Collaborative Ground Segments

Tags: data, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, copernicus

Is there an official list of all national mirrors of the [collaborative ground segment members](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/collaborative) for data from the [Copernicus Sentinel satellites](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions)?

So far I found the following:

- [Copernicus Sentinels Scientific Datahub (SciHub)](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/)
- [Australia National Mirror](http://www.copernicus.gov.au/)
- [Austria National Mirror](https://data.sentinel.zamg.ac.at/)
- [Finnish National Mirror](https://finhub.nsdc.fmi.fi/)
- [French National Mirror (PEPS)](https://peps.cnes.fr/rocket/)
- [German National Mirror (CODE-DE)](https://code-de.org/)
- [Greek National Mirror](https://sentinels.space.noa.gr/)
- [Italian National Mirror](http://collaborative.mt.asi.it/)

I am trying to piece together a [list of all national or partial mirrors](https://github.com/Fernerkundung/awesome-sentinel) but could not find any official list or document about the available national mirrors. Since each mirror requires a dedicated access to the central archive I was hoping that there is some kind of documentation about the existing or planned national mirrors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few days after the question was asked ESA started populating a list of existing and planned Collaborative Ground Segments and National Mirrors:

https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/collaborative/existing-planned

It does not look to be complete (yet) but for now it seems to be the only official source.

Answer (score 3):

I know the Swedish and Norwegian and British ones are operational or about to be operational.

I also found this resource which might be useful :

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/collaborative/national-points-of-contact

And there are large differences between Collaborative Ground Segments. Some deliver data all over the world (PEPS and probably Code-DE for instance), while others deliver them in their local area (which might be large, for instance central Europe for the Austrian CGS).

Answer (score 0):

In Slovenia we have based CollGS on Amazon Open data:
http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/

Depending on what you are searching for, you might want to test Sentinel Hub:
http://sentinel-hub.com/

Comment: Slovenia has a Collaborative Ground Segment based on AWS data? That is surprising - can you maybe link to that?